# Access ActionResult only from logged in users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a Login page that checks if the user is stored on the db. If the user is stored on the db I want to return an `ActionResult` called test. I have decorated the test `ActionResult` with the `[Authorise]` attribute however I get

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Scripts".

I only want users that have successfully logged in to be able to access that `ActionMethod`.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Login(UserModel user)
{
    var userValidation = new UserValidation();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (userValidation.IsValid(user.UserName, user.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, user.RememberMe);
            return RedirectToAction("Test", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");
        }
    }
    return View(user);
}

[Authorize]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    string currentlyLoggedInUser = User.Identity.Name;

    CustomerContactModelRepo _customerRepo = new CustomerContactModelRepo();
    return View(_customerRepo.GetCustomerContactForms());
}
```

This is my _Layout.cshtml page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sq">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/script.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Scripts/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="header-banner">
                HeaderBanner
            </div>
            <div id='cssmenu'>
                <ul>
                    <li class='active'>@Html.ActionLink("Index", "index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("ActionMethod1", "ActionMethod1", "Controller")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("ActionMethod2", "ActionMethod2", "Controller")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("AboutUs", "AboutUs", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("AnotherActionMethod", "AnotherActionMethod", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="body">
            <div id="body-main-left">Left Block</div>
            <div id="body-main-right">Right Block</div>
            <div id="body-main-center">@RenderBody()</div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="footer-table" >
                <table>
                    <tr colspan="2">ES Logo</tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error message is a view related error and has nothing to do with the code you have show. Show your code for the _Layout page where you have defined the section - it should be `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke _Layout page has been added :)

Comment: Nowhere in you `_Layout.cshtml` do I see `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` which means in your view, you likely have `@section scripts { ... }` which will cause that error.

Comment: @StephenMuecke adding RenderSection("scripts", required: false) does fix the error however the view being claled doenst have a section scripts code. The only difference is that its being decorated with the Authorize filter, if the filter is removed it works without having to add RenderSection("scripts", required: false) to the _Layout file. The at sign was removed because stackoverflow thought i was addressing multiple users.

Comment: You put code in comments inside backticks which means you can add the `@` symbol :) - refer [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). The error is related to `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`. If the user is not authorized you will be redirecting to the login page which maybe does have `@section scripts { ... }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke ahh off course it does. You are correct. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is a view related exception that is caused when a view includes `@section scripts { ... }` and uses a layout that does not include `@RenderSection("scripts")`.

In your case, either the `Test.cshtml` view or the `Login.cshtml` view contains `@section scripts`

Modify you layout to include

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

either in the `<head>` (after the scripts you have already declared) or immediately before the closing `</body>` tag